# Page title covert to URL link with France language in zendFramwork

Tags: php, zend-framework2, meta-tags, page-title

I am using ZendFramwork and have 2 language are English and France. It's run well when it's English but for France language, it's always have problem when it's contain spacial character like `é, á, ó,..`. It's will show Link URL of file to replace page tile even used Function convert language of php or set uft-8 to help but it's still nothing to effect. Here is my picture [image]

Anyone have any idea to help me! I am looking to see your reply soon, thanks .

Comment: Please show the code which converts/sets the title...

Comment: Have you tried passing the title through [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: Many thanks @FDL, I seen don't understand with 'htmlentities' and 'htmlspacailchars'?

Comment: **Show us your code** so we can help. Without seeing the code it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Yes this is my code `<?php echo convert($this->translate('equipmentName')); ?>` and `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" > `

Comment: Try `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(convert($this->translate('equipmentName'))); ?>`

Comment: I have test it's with `htmlspecialchars` but still the same :(

Comment: Many thanks to  @FDL , by i review your function now i can fixed it by  `echo (htmlentities(equipmentName));`

Answer (score 1):

For France language you should required replace all the special character with corresponding character.

Comment: Did you mean like `é` = `&egrave;` ? if that i also have to test already but still not work

Comment: From website URL : é replace with e.
For page Title you can htmlspecialchars function like below is my site URL this site is in Brazil Language. Its title in brazil lanauge with special character.
http://www.oinsider.com.br/empresas/tag/setor/petroleo-e-gas/?criteria=1

Answer (score 0):

Try to put content-type meta tag before the title tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo convert($this->translate('equipmentName')); ?></title>
```

Comment: `charset=utf-8`  i  am like used to used already but like no effect on it